# Is there a way to provide custom styles for active collapsibles in collapsible-sets of jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I am trying to restyle the default behavior of a collapsible heading in a collapsible-set when it is active, i.e. after having been tapped on. I looked through the demos at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html, however, none of the suggested data-theme roles seem to solve my problem.
I also looked through the styles in the jquery.mobile.collapsible.css but could not find anything that I thought could help me.

If I go with the default, E.G.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
<h3>Expanded header</h3>
<p>Some content goes here.</p>/div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3>Collapsed heading</h3>
<p>The hidden content</p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3>ANother collapsed heading</h3>
<p>I hope you will see this at some point</p>
</div>

</div>
```

the active header appears in blue. At this point I am not sure which styles I should trigger (overwrite) to get the blue disappear so that I can either inherit the styles of the underlying page or assign my own background color.

Thanks for any help.